# propensity from classification tree - mlib spark

Tags: apache-spark, classification

I am building a predictive model to predict the propensity of a customer to make purchase based on some dependent variable. I am using a decision tree. I need the propensity to purchase between 0 to 1. How do I get these values, since my target is binary 1 or 0 (will by or not)

How to do this in mlib spark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing classification and regression problems. If you need just prediction whether or not the customer will buy something, you need a classification model. If you want to predict the probability for the customer to buy something, you need a regression model. Refer to the MLlib documentation (http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/api/python/pyspark.mllib.html#module-pyspark.mllib.tree).

Training classifier model is done with `trainClassifier`, while regressor model training is done with `trainRegressor`. Here's an example in Python from the official documentation:

```
>>> from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint
>>> from pyspark.mllib.tree import DecisionTree
>>> from pyspark.mllib.linalg import SparseVector
>>>
>>> sparse_data = [
...     LabeledPoint(0.0, SparseVector(2, {0: 0.0})),
...     LabeledPoint(1.0, SparseVector(2, {1: 1.0})),
...     LabeledPoint(0.0, SparseVector(2, {0: 0.0})),
...     LabeledPoint(1.0, SparseVector(2, {1: 2.0}))
... ]
>>>
>>> model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(sc.parallelize(sparse_data), {})
>>> model.predict(SparseVector(2, {1: 1.0}))
1.0
>>> model.predict(SparseVector(2, {1: 0.0}))
0.0
>>> rdd = sc.parallelize([[0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0]])
>>> model.predict(rdd).collect()
[1.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: When the response in training dataset is binary can we still use a trainRegressor?

Comment: It depends on the analytical library. In sklearn, for instance, for most of the classifiers you have a "predict_proba" method that predicts probability for each of the classes instead of predicting the class. But for MLlib decision tree you don't have it so you have no other option but to use regression